# How to drag and drop UITextField using SpriteKit in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am using SpriteKit animation in my iOS application at first time. My aim is to drag and drop label, image and textfield. I have done it for label and image using `SKLabelNode` and `SKSpriteNode`.

Globally I declared,

```
var deltaPoint = CGPointZero
var selectedNode = SKNode()
```

First I created label, image, textfield in `didMoveToView` method. Then added label and image as child node and textfield as subview like below mentioned code.

```
   let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2 + 20, 200, 40))
    textField.center = view.center
    textField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    textField.tag = 101
    textField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)
    textField.placeholder = "Enter your name here"
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textField.autocorrectionType = .Yes
    textField.keyboardType = .Default
    textField.clearButtonMode = .WhileEditing
    textField.enabled = true
    view.addSubview(textField)

    let imageNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "images.jpg")
    imageNode.name = kMovableImageNodeName
    imageNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(imageNode)

    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
    labelNode.name = kMovableLabelNodeName
    labelNode.text = "Welcome"
    labelNode.fontSize = 30
    labelNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(labelNode)
```

In TouchesBegan method, set touched node to selected node.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        labelNode.zPosition = 0
        imageNode.zPosition = 0
        let positionInScene = touches.first?.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene!)
        selectedNode = touchedNode
        selectedNode.zPosition = 1
    }
```

In TouchesMoved method, setting delta point value

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let currentPoint = touches.first?.locationInNode(self)
        let previousPoint :CGPoint = (touches.first?.previousLocationInNode(self))!
        deltaPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint!.x - previousPoint.x, currentPoint!.y - previousPoint.y)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        selectedNode.zPosition = 1
        deltaPoint = CGPointZero
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        selectedNode.zPosition = 0
        deltaPoint = CGPointZero
    }
```

In update method, setting new point to selected node

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    let newPoint = CGPointMake(selectedNode.position.x + self.deltaPoint.x, self.selectedNode.position.y + self.deltaPoint.y)
    selectedNode.position = newPoint
    deltaPoint = CGPointZero
}
```

Like this how to drag and drop the textfield and when user double tapped the textfield, have to show keyboard.

Comment: two different technologies, UIKit and SpriteKit do not work together in the way you want it to.  You have to use your view controller to handle anything involving UIKit objects